# Create multiple div with multiple elements dynamically using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in javascript, I want to create div which have multiple div and multiple elements.See code below

```html
<style>
    .list-group li {
        list-style: none;
    }

    .panel-info, .panel-rating, .panel-more1 {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 10px;
        height: 60px;
    }

    .icon {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
    }

    .header {
        background-color: #f44336;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div id="listContainer">
    <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li>

                <div class="panel-body panel panel-default" style="height: 70px;">
                    <div class="panel-info">
                        <p><strong>Shailendra Kushwah</strong></p>

                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-more1">
                        <img src="img/feestatus/cancel-button.png" class="icon" />
                        <br /><span>Installment 1</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-more1">
                        <img src="img/feestatus/cancel-button.png" class="icon" />
                        <br /><span>Installment 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-more1">
                        <img src="img/feestatus/cancel-button.png" class="icon" />
                        <br /><span>Installment 3</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to create element of Div `id="listContainer"` dynamically on the basis of length of my array using loop.Please help

Comment: What is this array? I mean what does it contain information to diaplay in table by any chance?

Comment: share what have you tried with js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no js, no array. But independent of all those,

If you want to add an element to the current DOM structure,

First, you need to create it.

```
var new_element = document.createElement('div') 
//might be p, span, ol, li, a, section etc.
```

Then append it wherever you want.

```
var my_container = document.getElementById("my-container")
my_container.appendChild(new_element);
/* 
* for most bottom of current dom node
* document.body.appencdChild(new_element)
*/
```

Hence you have a reference to that element, you can set attributes via javascript.

```
new_element.setAttribute('id', 'new-element-id')
//<div id='new-element-id' ... 
new_element.classList.add('lorem')
//<div id='new-element-id' class='lorem' ...
new_element.classList.add('ipsum')
//<div id='new-element-id' class='lorem ipsum' ...
```

If you want to add multiple elements, this is also not difficult.

```
var giants = ['marx', 'engels', 'lenin']
for(i=0; i<giants.length; i++) {
   var g = document.createElement('div');
   g.setAttribute('id', giants[i]);
   document.body.appendChild(g);
}
```

or, more stylish

```
giants.forEach(function(e) { 
  var g = document.createElement('div'); 
  g.setAttribute('id', e); 
  document.body.appendChild(g);  
})
```

below snippet will add 5 divs (including images and span and span texts) with some data.

```js
insert_divs = function() {
  var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("panel-body")[0];
  var installments = ['Installment 1', 'Installment 2', 'Installment 3', 'Installment 4', 'Installment 5'];
  
  installments.forEach(function(e){
   
   var sp = document.createElement('span');
   var img = document.createElement('img'); 
   var installment = document.createElement('div');
   
   var span_text = document.createTextNode(e);
   sp.appendChild(span_text);

   img.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_cancel_48px-128.png')
   installment.classList.add('panel-more1');
   
   installment.appendChild(img);
   installment.appendChild(sp);
   
   parent.appendChild(installment);

  });
  


}

window.onload = insert_divs
```

```html
<div id="listContainer">
    <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li>
                <div class="panel-body panel panel-default" style="height: 70px;">
                    <div class="panel-info">
                        <p><strong>Shailendra Kushwah</strong></p>

                    </div>

               </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so, where do you want to append child elements? and what is your array (you stated before, length of array was basis)?

Comment: you can take any number for length of array

Comment: run my code snippet and see example ,in example i show one item of my list